# Solve $\int^2_{-1} (1-x)dx$ by thinking in terms of area?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

On our last quiz in Calculus 1, my professor asked us to solve $\int^2_{-1} (1-x)dx$ by thinking in terms of area. I don't know what he means by, "thinking in terms of area". I can solve it myself, but I didn't get full points, because I wasn't able to ask him what he meant.

How can I solve this "by thinking in terms of area"?

$$\int^2_{-1} (1-x)dx$$

$$=\int^2_{-1} 1 - \int^2_{-1}x$$

$$=x - \frac{x^2}{2}+C$$

---

$$\underset{x\to -1}\lim (x - \frac{x^2}{2}) = -1 - \frac{1}{2}=-\frac{3}{2}$$

$$\underset{x\to 2}\lim (x - \frac{x^2}{2}) = 2 - \frac{4}{2}=0$$

---

$$\int^2_{-1} (1-x)dx=0-(-\frac{3}{2})=\frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: You may first sketch the graph of $y=1-x$ for $-1\le x\le 2$.

Comment: Basically it is just the area under a triangle if you sketch it, no real integration required

Comment: Perhaps he meant to draw the regions, which consist of two triangles, one of which lies below the $x$-axis.

Comment: Did you ever how definite integrals represent areas? If not, that's what you have to learn. It's most likely in your class notes or textbook.

Comment: Usually one writes $x-\frac {x^2}2 |_{-1}^2\;$ rather than lim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integration computes the area between the graph and the axis. The red and blue region will cancel out.

What is left is the purple region which has area $1^2+\frac12 = \frac32$

[image]

Remark: Btw, $\lim_{x \to -1}(x-\frac{x^2}2)= - \frac32$.

Comment: Nice picture (+1); how did you make it?

Comment: Thanks, I use [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bkg64m9pok).

Comment: That really makes things clear, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That integral is the area of the triangle whose vertices are $(-1,2)$, $(-1,0)$, and $(1,0)$ minus the area of the triangle whose vertices are $(1,0)$, $(2,0)$, and $(2,-1)$. So,$$\int_{-1}^21-x\,\mathrm dx=2-\frac12=\frac32.$$

Comment: Should be $\color{red}2-\dfrac12=\dfrac{\color{red}3}2;$  OP previously had evaluated the integral incorrectly

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

1): $\displaystyle{\int_{-1}^{2}}1 dx $:

The area of a rectangle from $x=-2$ to $x=1$ on the $x-$axis  of height $1$, i.e.

$A_1 =3\cdot 1=3.$

2) Consider $y=x$ :

$\displaystyle{\int_{-1}^{2}}(x)dx $:

Negative contribution from $x=-1$ to $x=0$ on the $x$-axis:

$(1/2)(-1)(1)=-1/2;$

Positive contribution from $x=0$ to $x=2$ on the $x-$axis.

$(1/2)(2)(2)=2$;

Adding negative and positive contributions:

$A_2= 2 -(1/2)=3/2;$

Difference: 1)-2) :

$ A_1-A_2= 3-(3/2)=3/2$;